# Progressbar is not changing progress in loop

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have problem with changing status in my progress bar on my app.
I have while loop which is changing status from 1-100 every 100ms.
Loop works cause when I'm making Log checker which shows how much is actually equals "I" it's from 1-100.
When i'm putting manualy progress to for example 50 it shows but nothing change.

```
class StartActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var progressBar: ProgressBar? = null
    private val handler = Handler()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start)


        progressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar_activityStart)

        startProgressBar()
    }

    private fun startProgressBar() {
        progressBar!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        var i: Int = progressBar!!.progress
        progressBar!!.progress = 0

        Thread {
            while (i < 100) {
                i += 1
                handler.post {
                    progressBar!!.progress = i
                    Log.v("progress", i.toString())
                }
                try {
                    progressBar!!.progress = i
                    Thread.sleep(100)
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
            progressBar!!.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }.start()
    }
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".StartActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_activityStart_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logohorizontal" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_activityStart"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_activityStart_logo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_activityStart_logo"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try running this line `progressBar!!.progress = i` on the UI thread.

Comment: I know what happend. When I'm using RelativeLayout it makes no reason in progress bar. When I changed it to the Linear for example it works. WTF

Comment: Glad you figured it out, it might have gotten pushed out of the screen because of the RelativeLayout. Either way, if you figured it out you should answer your own question or edit your question and add the answere so other people could use it.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, then i changed

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_activityStart"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

to this:

```
<android.widget.ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_activityStart"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

then its worked. dont know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar`.